# Paramiko: password + sms-passcode autentification

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I need to connect to a server using ssh from Python.
Usually I use Paramiko, but this server requires a passcode that is sent on SMS after the password is entered:

```
C:\>ssh user@hostname.com
AD Password: <password>
Enter PASSCODE: <sms passcode>
```

Is it possible via Paramiko / Python

Comment: Are you referring to keyboard-interactive?

Comment: I think so, as the sms passcode is not sent before the password is entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work in my case:

```
def interactive_auth_handler(title, instructions, prompt_list):
    if prompt_list:
        if prompt_list[0][0]=="AD Password: ":
            return [password]
        return [getpass.getpass(prompt_list[0][0])]
    return []


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(host, port, username=username, password=password, pkey=None)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
    transport = client.get_transport()
    transport.auth_interactive(username, interactive_auth_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending long time and struggling with paramiko I came into know that **paramiko** already took care of two factor authentication with `auth_interactive_dumb(username)` method where no need to write own handler. it keep asking question from server and sending prompted input one by one. so first gets verified then second and so on.. I coded long line but this method gives you very short code for handling multiple questions(password, passcode, pataphrase, re-entring new token after waiting few minutes. etc...) asked by server :

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, 22))
ts = paramiko.Transport(sock)
ts.start_client(timeout=10)
ts.auth_interactive_dumb(username)
print(ts)
```

When you will print ts it will return **active** inside paramiko object if successfully verified each step.
If you want to execute command then you have to open channel on this transport object.